# Find max: $\frac{a}{b+2a}+\frac{b}{c+2b}+\frac{c}{a+2c}$

Tags: inequality, maxima-minima

For $a,b,c>0$ and $abc=1$. Find max:
$\frac{a}{b+2a}+\frac{b}{c+2b}+\frac{c}{a+2c}$

Comment: I'll have to make you angry by asking "what have you tried so far?"

Comment: Sorry to type this as an answer, but I can't make comments. The condition $abc = 1$ is irrelevant, since if all of $a$, $b$, $c$ are multiplied by the same factor $t$, the expression doesn't change. So I would ask whether this is really the way the question was posed.

Comment: Have you tried using Lagrange Multipliers? That's the usual method when you want to maximize a function subject to constraints.

Comment: Related: [Olympiad inequality $\frac{a}{2a + b} + \frac{b}{2b + c} + \frac{c}{2c + a} \leq 1$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1371054)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint1** 
$2LHS=3-(\frac{b}{b+2a}+\frac{c}{c+2b}+\frac{a}{a+2c})$ 
**Hint2**
Apply Cauchy-schwarz:
$[ b(b+2a)+c(c+2b)+a(a+2c)][\frac{b}{b+2a}+\frac{c}{c+2b}+\frac{a}{a+2c} ]\ge [a+b+c]^2$

Answer (score 1):

We will prove: $\frac{a}{b+2a}+\frac{b}{c+2b}+\frac{c}{a+2c}\le 1$ (1)

$(1)\Leftrightarrow \frac 1{\frac ba+2}+\frac 1{\frac cb+2}+\frac 1{\frac ac+2}\le 1 $.
Denoting $x=\frac ba, y=\frac cb, z=\frac ac$, we get

$x,y,z>0; xyz=1; \frac 1{x+2}+\frac 1{y+2}+\frac 1{z+2}\le 1$ (2)

$(2)\Leftrightarrow \frac {\frac 12(x+2)-\frac x2}{x+2}+\frac {\frac 12(y+2)-\frac y2}{y+2}+\frac {\frac 12(z+2)-\frac z2}{z+2}\le 1$

We write the last inequality as $\frac x{x+2}+\frac y{y+2}+\frac z{z+2}\ge 1$
and so it is enough to prove that $\frac x{x+2}\ge \frac{\sqrt[3]{x^2}}{\sqrt[3]{x^2}+\sqrt[3]{y^2}+\sqrt[3]{z^2}}$ (3)

We have

$x(\sqrt[3]{x^2}+\sqrt[3]{y^2}+\sqrt[3]{z^2})=x\sqrt[3]{x^2}+x\sqrt[3]{y^2}+x\sqrt[3]{z^2}\ge x\sqrt[3]{x^2}+2\sqrt{x\sqrt[3]{y^2}.x\sqrt[3]{z^2}}$

$=x\sqrt[3]{x^2}+2\sqrt[6]{x^6.y^2.z^2}$

$=x\sqrt[3]{x^2}+2\sqrt[3]{x^2}$

$=\sqrt[3]{x^2}(x+2)$

(3) is proved.
Of course, we have two other similar inequalities.
The equality when $a=b=c=1$ and the maximum value is $1$

Comment: +1. How did you think of inequality (3)?