# Generalization of an Olympiad Inequality

Tags: inequality, optimization, contest-math, maxima-minima, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Inspired by [this Olympiad inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1371054/64809) I ask the following question for $k > 0$.

> Find
>   $$\max_{a>0,b>,c>0}\Big(\frac{a}{ka + b} + \frac{b}{kb + c} + \frac{c}{kc + a}\Big).$$

Is it $\frac3{k+1}$ when $a=b=c$?

Comment: your Maximum holds only if $k>2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not $\frac{3}{k+1}$.

Try $k=1$.

In this case we obtain
$$\frac{a}{a+b}+\frac{b}{b+c}+\frac{c}{c+a}\leq\frac{3}{2},$$
which is wrong for $c\rightarrow0^+$, $a=1$ and $b=\frac{1}{2}$.

For $k\geq2$ the maximum is $\frac{3}{k+1}$.

Indeed, for $a=b=c$ we get a value $\frac{3}{k+1}$ and it's enough to prove that
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{ka+b}\leq\frac{3}{k+1}$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{a}{ka+b}-\frac{1}{k+1}\right)\leq\frac{3}{k+1}-\frac{3}{k} \tag1$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{b}{ka+b}\geq\frac{3}{k+1},$$
which follows from C-S:
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{b}{ka+b}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{b^2}{kab+b^2}\geq\frac{(a+b+c)^2}{\sum\limits_{cyc}(kab+b^2)}$$
$$=\frac{3}{k+1}\frac{(k+1)(a+b+c)^2}{3\sum\limits_{cyc}(kab+a^2)}=\frac{3}{k+1}\frac{(k-2)\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^2-ab)+3\sum\limits_{cyc}(kab+a^2)}{3\sum\limits_{cyc}(kab+a^2)}\geq$$
$$\geq\frac{3}{k+1}\frac{3\sum\limits_{cyc}(kab+a^2)}{3\sum\limits_{cyc}(kab+a^2)}=\frac{3}{k+1}.$$
For $0<k<2$ the supremum is $\frac{2}{k}$, which we can prove by the same way.

Done!

Comment: this holds only if $k>2$, if $0<k<2$ we get $$\frac{2}{k}$$ and $1$ if $k=2$

Comment: Sonnhard  Yes of course!

Comment: My Name is Sonnhard, Michael!

Comment: What motivates you to turn this problem into a minimization problem like Equation (1)?

Comment: @Hans Because I want to use C-S and C-S it's $\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{a^2}{b}\geq...$. There is a way to use C-S also like this: $\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{a}{ka+b}\leq...$, but I did not find how I can end this way here.

Comment: Can you give an example of using C-S like $\sum\frac{a}{ka+b}\le\cdots$ without or without cyclic sum?

Comment: $\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{a}{2a+b}=\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{a}{a+a+b}\leq\frac{1}{9}\sum\limits_{cyc}a\left(\frac{1^2}{a}+\frac{2^2}{a+b}\right)=\frac{1}{9}\left(3+4\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{a}{a+b}\right).$

Comment: Hahahaa, I see you are playing the same trick on each fraction. Fine.